# Delete or Move files from the cloud to my computer

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am at the limit of my 15 Gb storage on the cloud ans I don't know how to
1 DELETE files on the cloud
2 MOVE files from the cloud to my computer
Thank you for your help in this matter

Comment: Personal computing questions, including using Google Drive for individuals, are not on topic on Server Fault. Try Super User. (Or Google One support.)

Comment: You have Google Cloud Platform tagged. Which service are you using? Which user guide have you read? The exact steps require knowing which service you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Log into your Cloud Account, open Windows Explorer, COPY the files you wish to your local computer, and then go back to the Cloud folder and delete the files you copied.

Copy first, delete second prevents accidents and lost data.